# WatchKit app launch another Watchkit application pp

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

Is it possible to Watchkit app to launch another WatchApp such a Call app in the Watch. Actually I developing a app it need to open the call app in watch

Answer (score 1):

Currently WatchKit does not allow you to launch another app, rather you can call parent app which is on the iPhone. Also communication between iWatch app and parent app is possible using `openParentApplication`. But there's zero possibility for the scenario that you are saying. 
Refer this documentation: [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply:)